# Writing a linear equation defining the subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

**Write a linear equation defining the subspace of R3 spanned by v1=(0,0,2) and v2=(−3,1,−1).**

__________ = 0

**(Write your answer in the form ax+by+cz. For example "2x+3y−4z")**

I have this question to solve, but I don't have any idea how to solve this. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: One very straight forward way would be to simply solve for $a, b, c$ in the given form. That is, find $a, b, c$ such that $0a + 0b + 2c = 0$ and $-3a + 1b - 1c = 0$. You should only need one solution. A more clever way involves cross products, if you've encountered them yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every element of your linear subspace can be written as a linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$. If $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2, z_3)$ both satisfy 
$$ax+by+cz=0$$
then so does any linear combination of the two. Since $v_1, v_2$ span a 2 dimensional subspace of a 3 dimensional space, we only need one equation to describe it, and both $v_1$ and $v_2$ must solve it. So we need
$$a*0 +b*0 + c*2=0$$
and
$$a*(-3)+b*(1)+c*(-1)=0$$

Solving these equations gives $(a,b,c)$ up to some factor that we can choose, since
 $$ax+by+cz=0$$
and
$$kax+kby+kcz=0$$
have the same solution set if $k\neq 0$

Comment: I'm kind of confused. How do I do the cross product to those? If possible can I have the answer to the question, please?

Comment: The cross product option @user764828 mentions uses that $v_1×v_2$ is orthogonal to both $v_1$ and $v_2$, so you can take $(a,b,c)$ to be the entries in the cross product.  Alternatively, if you solve the above equations, you get $c=0$ and $b=3a$. You can then choose non zero number for $a$, so your answer could be $(1,3,0)$, say.